# Ubuntu 22.04 Graphical Issue with Nvidia 390 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

when I ran ubuntu's installer and clicked on the first option try or install ubuntu it just showed me a blank blinking "-", and when I chose the second option, Ubuntu (safe graphics) it worked and installed, however when my Graphics Card is in the CPU. it doesnt show load into the system however it works fine with it out but slower, the graphics card I'm using is Nvidia NVS 315 please tell me how to fix this issue

lspci output:

```
zain@zain-OptiPlex-755:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
```

I have my GHraphics Card (Nvidia NVS 315 unplugged because it wont boot at all with it installed so I had to physically remove it from my computer

Comment: Which Ubuntu version did you install?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci` to the question via an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506469/edit).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Nvidia 390 drivers from Ubuntu repositories do not work with kernel 6.5. This is because Nvidia has stopped supporting the 390 driver.

There are two workarounds.

1. Use Ubuntu with lower kernel versions.
2. Install a patched Nvidia driver that can be found [at Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/390.157-0ubuntu8/)

Comment: thankyou, but can you tell me which exact version of kernal should I use? as I am new to Linux like I have just started using the application, if you can please send me a link of ubantu with lower kernal versions so I can just create a bootable flash and boot up the system. I will be very thankful sir

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you are trying to install? If it is an LTS, you can change kernel without re-install.

Comment: yeah it is an LTS, 22.04 version I believe, the current kernal version is 6.5

Comment: You can run `sudo apt install linux-generic`, boot with the 5.15 kernel and all should work. Then remove the 6.5 kernel packages. Or you can install a patched driver. It works with the 6.5. I am using it.

Comment: thankyou with your help I was able to get my system running with the graphics card! lots of love